# Перенаправление одной сетевой на другую : eth0 ---->> eth1

Tags: windows-7, маршрутизация

Имеется ПК с устанвленной семеркой, и двумя сетевухами. К одной из них идет инет. Т.е. eth0 и eth1;
Инет идет по eth0;  IP статический вида 172.ххх.ххх.ххх в сетке провайдера, также есть выделенный IP вида 91.200.ххх.ххх который используется только для инета   
Задача: необходимо перенаправить входящий траффик c eth0, на eth1, для подключения ТВ к интернету
Как это можно сделать? подсобите.

Comment: Чет не совсем понятно. Уточните, пожалуйста, каким образом подключается ТВ к инету, какой ip назначен eth0, какой eth1.

Answer (score 1):

Объедините сетевые интерфейсы в мост (bridge).